# How to center buttons in image using Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, bootstrap-4

I have two adjacent responsive images, each with a button that I would like to be centered in the image. Right now the buttons are just sitting below the images. Here is my code

```
<!--LAB1-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
<div class="view overlay">
<img class="img-fluid" src="img/lab1.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">
<div class="text center">
<a  href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary" role="button">Lab1 Website
<div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div style="height: 10px"></div>

<!--LAB2-->
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-lg-6"
<div class="view overlay">
<img class="img-fluid" src="img/lab2.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary" role="button">Lab2 Website
<div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[attached an image of what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6tZY.png)

Comment: using `text-center` with `view overlay` may help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference link you can use

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_button_on_image.asp

Or else

Simply add below CSS code for button

```
position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Here is fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/L1aknvgs/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add position relative to the parent of button. Then add position absolute to the button.

```
.btn{
position: absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Attached an example: [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/iahmadhabibx/pen/dyovWWm)

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4, You can use this as follow and in CSS the left and top percentage depend on the pixels of an image, below I provide your code with modification.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="view overlay">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="text center">
                    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary button_position" role="button">Lab1 Website</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.button_position {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  top: 40%;
}
```

and here is the fiddle, 
https://jsfiddle.net/vbsgfo9k/1/